# SequelizeConnectionError 127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize.js

no logro conectar my proyecto de `node` con `mysql`.

Vi varios sitios con este error, aplique lo que dicen y no funciona igualmente

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("matias", "root","Matute1511", {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect:"mysql",
    port: "127.0.0.1",
    pool: {max: 10, min: 0, acquire: 30000, idle: 10000}
});
```

**//error de consola**

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ENOENT 127.0.0.1
> at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:149:19)
>
> ```
> at tryCatcher (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>
> at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
>
> at Promise._settlePromise (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
>
> at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
>
> at Promise._settlePromises (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:725:18)
>
> at _drainQueueStep (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
>
> at _drainQueue (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
>
> at Async._drainQueues (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
>
> at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/matias/Desktop/iot.vasconisolutions/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
>
> at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)                                                                                                                                                        
> at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)                                                                                                                                                      
> at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Creo observar que estas confundiendo puerto con host intenta con esto

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("matias", "root","Matute1511", {
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    dialect:"mysql",
    port: 3306,
    pool: {max: 10, min: 0, acquire: 30000, idle: 10000}
});
```

asumiendo que el puerto por default de mysql es 3306

Saludos